# Why does a ground plane change the radiation pattern for a PIFA antenna?

Tags: inductor, antenna

I have designed a PIFA antenna as shown below.

The problem is that the radiation pattern changes as a function of my ground dize.

I know that if the ground plane is large enough then the radiation pattern is stable, but in reality it is not.

One assumption I found is ground currents.
We need to cancel these ground currents with a choke.

A choke is basically an inductor, in high frequency it is an open circuit.

I have a PIFA antenna.  How can I implement this principle here?

Is there some article I could read which could help me solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you doing in that plot? Are you moving the feed point?

Comment: And do you really mean "ratio pattern" (which I have never heard of), or "radiation pattern"?

Comment: yes my radiation pattern changes with the function of GND size.

Comment: When ground and patch are equal area, it's just a compact dipole.  When ground is very large (limit towards infinity), it's equivalent to a monopole.  Intermediate values are somewhere inbetween. Perhaps consider building a dipole proper, so that ground currents balance out, and then it will be insensitive to ground size.

Comment: "I know that if the ground plane is large enough then the radiation pattern is stable" — yes, if it's large enough to approximate an infinite plane, but that means *many wavelengths* in the shortest dimension. Otherwise, some variation with the geometry of the ground plane should be expected. It would appear yours is around 1 wavelength in size.

Comment: Many times, antenna element (patches, notches, folded notches, stacked notches, etc) designers spend hours with appropriate modeling tools just to optimize the placement of the feed point.

Comment: Hello , i have expanded my ground plane to be 2 wavelength in size, and it ruined my mating completly.In the manual we only have formulas for the PIFA PATCH.

the feeding point of the patch says how much its inductive or capacitative. 
the inductive part cancells the capacitative part.
In the smith chart shown bellow,it gained lots of ressistance.
What is the intuition for matching back my antenna with the current ground plane.


https://ibb.co/BjZz35R